# I need to find a specific value in an array of arrays. Angular, Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I need to find a value in an array of arrays, but when I use the .find it returns undefined

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import { ExcelSheetsService } from '../services/excel-sheets.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-hojaexcel',
  templateUrl: './hojaexcel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hojaexcel.component.css']
})
export class HojaexcelComponent implements OnInit {

  
  constructor( private excelsheetService: ExcelSheetsService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  codigo: any = ''; 
  datos: [][] = [];
  

  onFileChange( evt: any  ){

  
    
  const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer> (evt.target);

  if(target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error ('No se pueden subir varios archivos a la vez');

  const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = ( e: any ) => {
    const bstr: string = e.target.result;

    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read( bstr, { type: 'binary' } );

    const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];

    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

    this.datos = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
    console.log(this.datos);

    return this.datos;

  }; 

  reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);

  }

  look(): any{
    
    const found = this.datos.find(element => element == this.codigo );
    console.log(found);
    console.log(this.datos);
    

  }


  


  pasardata(){
    this.excelsheetService.impData( this.datos )
      .subscribe( resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      });

  }



  

}
```

The array of arrays is datos. And this is the Html:

```
<p>Subir Archivo excel</p>
<br>

<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false" />

<br>

<button (click)="pasardata()">
    Subir a base de datos Firebase
</button>

<br>

<div class="col">
    <form (ngSubmit)="look()">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Codigo" name="codigo" [(ngModel)]="codigo"/>


        <button>Enviar</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

I have tried to access to the datos array of arrays and it returns an empty array, I want to use the array of arrays to display a table an after this get an specific value of the table, using .find().

Comment: If datos is an array of array, your this.datos.find(element => element == this.codigo ) element will be always an array. But this. codigo is a string, this will never equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `datos: [][]` is a nested array of strings, you could use `flatMap` with `find`:

```
const found = this.datos
  .flatMap(element => element) // flatten nested array
  .find(element => element === this.codigo);
```

That being said, if `datos` is a nested array of objects, you can't simply compare `{} === {}`, you would need to compare against some kind of property object:

```
const found = this.datos
  .flatMap(element => element) // flatten nested array
  .find(element => element.someProperty === this.codigo);
```

Version without `flatMap`:

```
const found = this.datos
  .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr))
  .find(element => element === this.codigo);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I am getting this error:                                              src/app/hojaexcel/hojaexcel.component.ts:56:30 - error TS2550: Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type '[][]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2019' or later.

56     const found = this.datos.flatMap( element => element ).find(element => element == this.codigo );

Comment: It would require a specific target version to allow the use of flatMap. Let me make another version as an option.

Comment: Thanks, I already fixed the error TS2550, and the code runs, but it stills returning undefined as result, and datos as an empty array. I get this: http://prntscr.com/10g9byv

Comment: @arnoldogonzalez Unfortunately a few things still unclear to properly troubleshoot. It's not clear what `datos` looks like before the `find` is executed. Can you do `console.log(this.datos) in `look()` and share the output?

Comment: This is the output: http://prntscr.com/10g9r0j    and here is where I do the console.log of "datos" and "found" http://prntscr.com/10g9svz

Comment: @arnoldogonzalez I'd avoid using screenshots to share this information and instead update your question with text. That being said, it looks like `datos` is not being loaded effectively? I'd first focus on getting `datos` to be loaded correctly, otherwise `find` will never work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already fixed. Thanks for your help!